# How can I prevent software from becoming default?

Tags: default-programs, xdg-open

I recently installed SMPlayer and it became default without even asking, is there a way to prevent software doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The default software is based for a file type format.

If you want to define it, follow the steps:

1. List item
2. Find a file with a format that you want to define (mp3,avi,.... )
3. Click right button on it
4. Click properties
5. Click "Open with" tab
6. Choose the software that you want.

That's it!